# SQL Group By and Having display fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having, having-clause

I’m trying to pull the people records associated with 405B folders where there is more than 1 folderpeople record.  I’ve used the following SQL to get the counts, but what I can’t figure out is how to pull the actual people information ,p.namefirst, p.namelast, p.organizationname, and fp.peoplecode.  I’ve tried using various permutations on GROUP BY and HAVING, but I keep getting errors.  I only want the data from folder, folder people and people where there is more than 1 folderpeople record.

```
SELECT f.folderrsn, Count(fp.folderrsn)
FROM folder f
INNER JOIN folderpeople fp ON f.folderrsn = fp.folderrsn
WHERE f.foldertype = '405B'
GROUP BY f.folderrsn
HAVING Count(fp.folderrsn) > 1
ORDER BY f.folderrsn
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I can add those fields fine but it will go from 500 records to less than that, I need all 500 with the fields I want.

Comment: can you add a bit off your data and show us what would you expect to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really understanding your schema or data (examples would really help here), it SOUNDS like you want something like this?

```
SELECT p.namefirst, p.namelast, p.organizationname, fp.peoplecode
  FROM folder f
       INNER JOIN folderpeople fp ON f.folderrsn = fp.folderrsn
WHERE fp.folderrsn IN (
    SELECT folderrsn
      FROM folder 
     WHERE folderType = '405B'
     GROUP BY folderrsn
    HAVING COUNT(folderrsn) > 1
)
```

Basically, select all the data you want from the tables you want, and then filter the results to only those where the folder matches your criteria.  So I may have the details wrong here, but this might give you the format you're looking for in how to combine a GROUP BY/HAVING with getting all the data from tables and columns you're not grouping on.

Comment: this is getting me somewhere, i'm trying it out and tweaking due to data. but yes, what you assumed is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have some sort of "persons" table that has columns that you reference in your question.  And this can be joined back to `folderpeople`.

Given that, you *could* solve the problem by joining the information back in.  That's a bit message, because you can also do this using window functions in SQL Server:

```
SELECT pf.*
FROM (SELECT p.*, f.folderrsn,
             count(*) over (partition by f.folderrsn) as cnt
      FROM folder f INNER JOIN
           folderpeople fp
           ON f.folderrsn = fp.folderrsn JOIN
           people p
           ON fp.personid = p.personid
      WHERE f.foldertype = '405B'
     ) pf
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY olderrsn;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'm surprised it took longer.